# como puedo Mostrar tablas html y en cada uno de estas otra tabla dentro de primer <td>

Tags: html, css

Mi idea es que solo ir imprimiendo tablas en mi index, pero quieren que una sola tabla muestre las tablas que se generen por un item por que después de que se termine de trabajar en una de las tablas de adentro, debe de eliminarse. Ademas de que serian mas de 100 tablas por que son mas de 100 items y en la tabla principal, trae un paginador y en cada pagina de la tabla mostrar 10 productos oseas 10 tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias especificar mas tu pregunta? que tecnologia usas para obtener los datos y si estas usando algun plugin. saludos

Comment: Los datos están directamente escritos en la tabla de momento, solo es html y bootstrap